# Python append a string after an occurrence of a pattern

Tags: python, xml, regex, string, markup

How do I append to a string after an occurrence of a pattern?? I know that strings are immutable. But if there is a way to do it?

Eg..
input:

```
condor  t   airline airline
eight   n   0   flightnumber
nine    n   0   flightnumber
five    n   0   flightnumber
hallo   t   0   sentence
```

expected output:

```
<s> <callsign> <airline> condor </airline> 
<flightnumber> eight nine five </flightnumber> 
</callsign> hallo </s>
```

Program:

```
import re
import string
import csv
out = ''
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
  for row in reader:
    if (row == "\n"):
        out += "\n"
    if 'airline' in row:
        print '<callsign> <airline>' + row[0] + '</airline></callsign>'
    if 'sentence' in row: 
        print '<s>' + row[0] + '</s>'
    if 'flightnumber' in row: 
        print '<flightnumber>' + row[0] + '</flightnumber>'
```

Produces:

```
<callsign> <airline>condor</airline></callsign>
<flightnumber>eight</flightnumber>
<flightnumber>nine</flightnumber>
<flightnumber>five</flightnumber>
<s>hallo</s>
```

Is there a way that I can make this^ to the one in expected output?

Comment: If this is XML, please use a real xml parser/library to write it (like lxml), otherwise you are pretty sure to get stuff like quoting and charsets wrong one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new string with the pattern replaced with itself followed by what you want to add, and replace the original string with the new one.

However, it looks like from your example, that you need more than simple replacements; you need to gather up the lines w/ `flightnumber` so you can combine their contents into one tag.

I think you'll need to provide more details on what rules you want to follow to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: thanks for looking over. I am trying to convert the given input into the given output where the input can be in any order ie. all details in various positions but needs to be processed to produce output as exactly given.The 2nd and 3rd words of each line can be ignored for that matter. So just having the first and last word the markup has to be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string format and zip to do this:

```
txt='''\
condor  t   airline airline
eight   n   0   flightnumber
nine    n   0   flightnumber
five    n   0   flightnumber
hallo   t   0   sentence'''

template='''\
<s> <callsign> <airline> {} </airline> 
<flightnumber> {} </flightnumber> 
</callsign> {} </s>'''

col=zip(*[line.split() for line in txt.splitlines()])[0]

print template.format(col[0], ' '.join(col[1:4]), col[4])
```

Prints:

```
<s> <callsign> <airline> condor </airline> 
<flightnumber> eight nine five </flightnumber> 
</callsign> hallo </s>
```

Comment: The main idea is to process the input.. I think hardcoding the format does not do enough justice..